# Rails 5.1 webpacker "import" a .js.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1, webpacker

From `app/javascript/packs/application.js` I'm trying to `import "../foo"` where the file is `foo.js.erb`.   Webpacker and yarn are working great for other imports in application.js, for example `import "../bar"` when that file is `bar.js` but if I try with a `.js.erb` file I get this error from webpack-dev-server:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../foo' in '/Users/blah/backlot/projects/test/app/javascript/packs'
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 3:0-27
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
```

I do have rails-erb-loader installed and if I look at the webpacker config, the erb loader is being evaluated and looks right to me although I didn't touch any of that except for running `rails webpacker:install` to generate that config.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If what you want to do is this:

```
import '../foo'
```

When the actual file is `foo.js.erb`, you need to update `config/webpack/webpacker.yml` to include

```
- .js.erb
```

In the list of extensions.  Otherwise you need to fully specify the file name you are importing

```
import '../foo.js.erb'
```

Comment: It seems it is no longer `config/webpack/paths.yml` but `config/webpack/webpacker.yml` that must be updated. Confusingly, the list of extensions already contains `- .erb`, but the extension to add is `- .js.erb`.

Comment: Don't forget to install .erb support for webpacker first: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb

Comment: Update for rails 6, the path is `config/webpacker.yml`

Comment: By fixing the file extension to `.js.erb` in config/webpacker.yml does not require to load as `import '../foo.js.erb'`.

Answer (score 14):

> To add Erb support in your JS templates, run `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb` on a Rails app already setup with Webpacker.

[source](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#erb) (from cseelus' comment)

Answer (score 8):

For rails 6.x, run `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb` and add the following to the `config/webpacker.yml`

```
extensions:
  - .erb
```

See [webpacker documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/integrations.md#erb) for more info:

Comment: Many thanks @fydelio It helped me to fix the same issue!